# How to implement a promise code snippet in place of Mysql client in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, async-await

My primitive purpose to ask for a solution was because, i want to use Observables because i want to obtain real-time data on angular UI. But here the issue is i get sql error --> Too many sql connections . So i need to close the connection everytime after the query hits the database. That is not happening in my code. So i searched for the codes available and found this -

https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-promises-4c3be599909b

nodejs code -

```
 const mysql = require( 'mysql' );
  class Database {
   constructor( config ) {
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection( config );
    }
   query( sql, args ) {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        this.connection.query( sql, args, ( err, rows ) => {
            if ( err )
                return reject( err );
            resolve( rows );
        } );
     } );
    }
   close() {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        this.connection.end( err => {
            if ( err )
                return reject( err );
            resolve();
        } );
    } );
    }
    }
```

Now i want to implement this above code in my nodejs file whose code is this -

[The http request from my angular hits the controller.js file first and then from there it hits the service.js file]

**UPDATED**

**dashboard.controller.js**

```
  var express = require('express');
  var router = express.Router();
  var dashboardService = require('../../services/SYSTEM
   /dashboard.service');
   var app = express();


    router.post('/abcEntireSuccess',abcEntireSuccess);

    module.exports = router;




  function abcEntireSuccess(req, res) {


    dashboardService.abcEntireSuccess(req.body)
          .then(function (result) {
          if (result.length > 0) {
            console.log("we get data in node :: " + 
        Object.values(result));
            console.log(result.length + " record found  ");
            res.send(result);
           } 
         else {
            result=[];
            res.send(result);
         }
       })
       .catch(function (err) {
        res.status(400).send(err);
        console.log("some error occured");
       });
       }
```

**dashboard.service.js**

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var Q = require('q');
    var express = require('express');
    var service = {};
    var config = require('../../config.json');
    const async = require('async');


       service.abcEntireSuccess = abcEntireSuccess;

        module.exports = service;


 function abcEntireSuccess() {

  var sqlQuery = `select * from TRANSACTION_PAYLOAD where INTERFACE_NAME =  
   'abc' AND (STATUS ='SUCCESS_RESPONSE')`



    var deferred = Q.defer();



    var host = config.host;
    var user = config.user;
    var password = config.password;
    var database = config.database;


     var con = mysql.createConnection({
     host: host,
     user: user,
     password: password,
     database: database
       });


      con.connect(function (err) {
       if (err) deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);

       con.query(sqlQuery,
           function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);

            console.log("my result => ",result);

            deferred.resolve(result);

        });


       })

     console.log(" deferred.promise; ");
    return deferred.promise;



  }
```

please help in the  implementation.

@skipperhoa

**UPDATED**

When i implement your code... i get this error in angular UI i.e. html ,

POST http://localhost:8096/dashboard/abcEntireSuccess/ 404 (Not Found)

Please help resolve

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following after code

```js
//dashboard.controller.js
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var dashboardService = require('./dashboard.service.js');

router.get('/test2',function(req,res){
  console.log(dashboardService.abcEntireSuccess());
});

module.exports = router


//dashboard.service.js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var config = require('../config/config.json');
var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.abcEntireSuccess = function() {
    const db = new Database(config);
    db.query( 'SELECT * FROM users' ).then( rows => {
        return rows;
    } );
db.close();
};

class Database {
    constructor( config ) {
        this.connection = mysql.createConnection( config.values);
    }
    query( sql, args ) {
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            this.connection.query( sql, args, ( err, rows ) => {
                if ( err )
                    return reject( err );
                console.log(rows);
                resolve( rows );
            } );
        } );
    }
    close() {
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            this.connection.end( err => {
                if ( err )
                    return reject( err );
                resolve();
            } );
        } );
    }
 }
```

```html
//congfig/config.json
{
    "values" : {
        "host" : "localhost",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "",
        "database" : "demo"
    }
}
```

Comment: i am trying to implement your code, but please check my question. I have updated it according to your reply. I have mentioned a controller file also , because in your code , everything seems to happen in only one example.js file. But it is not the case in my code. Please check. Thank you

Comment: I have update it , you can try see, you need create class Database call it in file  dashboard.service.js. after then you import file "dashboard.service.js" to "dashboard.controller.js", call function abcEntireSuccess()

Comment: Hey skipperhoa .... the code you gave, when i implemented it in  my program, i am getting an error that i pasted it here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51111931/error-post-httpabc-404-not-found-in-angular2-and-nodejs

Comment: in above snippet(answer),as u called db.query() likewise where do we  call close()

Comment: i have update it, you see again, after you called db.query(),after then you call db.close() in exports.abcEntireSuccess