# Error POST http:abc/ 404 (Not Found) in angular2+ and nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, async-await

I am making a `http` request from my `angular2+` code to database present in `node.js` file. The `ajax` call from `angular2+` hits the `controller.js` file and then redirects to `service.js` file which has the connection to the database:

```
angular.ts ==> controller.js ==> service.js
```

From the database the `service.js` file gives the output to `controller.js` file and then answers the `ajax` call to `angular.ts` file:

```
service.js ==> controller.js ==> angular.ts
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
POST http://localhost:8096/dashboard/abcEntireSuccess1/ 404 (Not Found)
```

**UPDATED**
    Cannot GET /dashboard/experianEntireSuccess1/

And one more issue -

```
   UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found
```

And one more issue -

After coming back from the hit in service.js which has the data i want      ==>    to => controller.js , here the data is acquired is undefined. As seen below -

The output on Nodejs -

output -

**service.js**

```
  closed connection
  yessss [ RowDataPacket { ....
```

**controller.js**

```
  we are coming back to controller undefined

  some error occured of abcEntireSuccess1
```

My Entire Code:
**UPDATED**

**abc.component.ts**

```
viewAbcEntireSuccess1() {


var url = config.url;
var port = config.port;


this.http.post("http://" + url + ":" + port + "/dashboard  
  /abcEntireSuccess1/", this.emptyObj
  , { headers: new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 
    localStorage.getItem('Token') }) })
  .map(resultConnection => this.resultConnection = 
    resultConnection.json(), )
   .subscribe((res: Response) => {

     this.records = res;

     this.resultConnectionlength = this.resultConnection.length;

   });

 }
```

**abc.controller.js**

```
  router.post('/experianEntireSuccess1',experianEntireSuccess1);
  module.exports = router;


    function abcEntireSuccess1(req, res) {


    dashboardService.abcEntireSuccess1(req.body)
      .then(function (result) {
        console.log("we are coming back to controller",result)
        if (result.length > 0) {
            console.log("we get data in node of abcEntireSuccess1 :: 
         " + Object.values(result));
            console.log(result.length + " record found  ");
            res.send(result);
           } 
         else {
            result=[];
            res.send(result);
         }
     })
     .catch(function (err) {
        res.status(400).send(err);
        console.log("some error occured of abcEntireSuccess1");
      });
      }
```

**abc.service.js**

```
  async function abcEntireSuccess1() {
  console.log("function called")
   const db = new Database();
   await db.query(`select * from TRANSACTION_PAYLOAD where INTERFACE_NAME
    = 'Abc' AND (STATUS ='SUCCESS_RESPONSE')`
    ).then(rows => {

    console.log("closed connection");

    console.log("yessss",rows)
    return rows;

     });
    };

   class Database {
   constructor() {

      this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        user: "abc",
        password: "abc",
        database: "DB"
      });

    }


  query(sql, args) {
    console.log("sql is", sql)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.connection.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
            console.log("connection function called")
            if (err) {
                console.log("error is", err)
                return reject(err);
            }

            console.log("rows are",rows);
            resolve(rows);
        });
       });
     }
   close() {

     console.log("calling connection close")
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("called connection close")
        this.connection.end(err => {
            if (err){
                return reject(err);
            }

            resolve();
        });
     });
     }
     }
```

Comment: viewAbcEntireSuccess1(data): Promise<any>{
    const url = `${this.url}/dashboard/abcEntireSuccess1`;
    return this.http.post(url,data {headers: this.getHeader.HTTPHeader() })
    .toPromise()
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

Comment: Take the values of header and url before calling anAPi

Comment: A 404 error suggests that the route can't be found. Can you post the full `abc.controller.js` file please?

Comment: you need add full url router, because angular and nodej run two diffet port, if angular is port 8000 and nodejs is 8086, you need change router in nodejs the following router.post('http://localhost:8096/dashboard/abcEntireSuccess1/',function(req,res)){}) , you try see

Comment: Hey Prashant, user184994 and skipperhoa, i updated my question please check.